# Apache httpd high CPU usage

Tags: java, linux, apache, jakarta-ee

Recent I am facing a big issue in my server, I am using tomcat as controller & apache as web-server, but suddenly apache consuming 98% of CPU , hence my site is hanging out , I killed this process many time but this process again starting up and consuming CUP again,may any one give some solution for that ?

LOG:

**root     21937 2264  5.8 9181548 246700 ?      SLl  08:44 3168:44 apache -c** httpd.conf
root     24842  0.0  0.0  27400  3220 ?        S    04:16   0:00 cpdavd - accepting connections on 2077, 2078, 2079, and 2080 (dormant)
root     28715  0.0  0.0 128548  3984 ?        S    09:15   0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     28726  0.0  0.0 128548  3984 ?        S    09:15   0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     29283  0.0  0.0 128548  3988 ?        S    09:18   0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     29391  0.0  0.0 128548  3980 ?        S    09:18   0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     29786  0.0  0.0 128548  3988 ?        S    09:20   0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     29825  0.0  0.0 128548  3988 ?        R    09:20   0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     29857  0.0  0.0 128548  3980 ?        S    09:20   0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     30022  0.0  0.0 128548  3980 ?        S    09:21   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     32218  0.0  0.0 128548  3844 ?        S    04:50   0:03 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     32223  0.0  0.0 128548  3984 ?        S    04:50   0:07 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     32284  0.0  0.0 128548  3984 ?        S    04:51   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     32311  0.0  0.0 128548  3984 ?        S    04:51   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     32342  0.0  0.0 128548  3988 ?        S    04:51   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     32345  0.0  0.0 128548  3984 ?        S    04:51   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     32349  0.0  0.0 128548  3980 ?        S    04:51   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     32354  0.0  0.0 128548  3980 ?        S    04:51   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     32373  0.0  0.0 128548  3988 ?        S    04:51   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     32409  0.0  0.0 128548  3980 ?        S    04:51   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     32493  0.0  0.0 128548  3980 ?        S    04:51   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     32551  0.0  0.0 128548  3984 ?        S    04:52   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     32567  0.0  0.0 128548  3988 ?        S    04:52   0:07 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     32657  0.0  0.0 128548  3980 ?        S    04:52   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     32751  0.0  0.0 128548  3980 ?        S    04:52   0:08 /usr/sbin/httpd

Comment: What is in the logs for httpd?

Answer (score -1):

The settings in httpd.conf (or apache2.conf depending on version) need to be tuned.

Running one of these two will tell you the amount of memory that Apache is using: 
ps -ylC httpd | awk '{x += $8;y += 1} END {print "Apache Memory Usage (MB): "x/1024; print "Average Proccess Size (MB): "x/((y-1)*1024)}'

ps -ylC apache2 | awk '{x += $8;y += 1} END {print "Apache Memory Usage (MB): "x/1024; print "Average Proccess Size (MB): "x/((y-1)*1024)}'

The first thing I'd tune is the prefork settings as well as the other IfModule sections in httpd.conf

Here are a couple of guides with lots of Apache tuning recommendations:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-apache-web-server-performance
http://www.monitis.com/blog/25-apache-performance-tuning-tips/

Comment: Apache not consuming memory, but it's consuming CPU (i. E.  99%)

Comment: What makes you think this?